# Embedding a Flash player in Google Earth kmz

Tags: flash, google-earth, kmz

I previously made a Google Earth kml that has embedded flash video content. To properly play the content in a  tag, I hosted a flash player (currently using flowplayer) on my webserver and used the following HTML within the description tag. This worked flawlessly:

```
            <description><![CDATA[ 
            <object id="flowplayer"
                    data="http://foo.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" width="320" height="180"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <param name="movie" value="http://foo.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" />
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"http://foo.com/movies/flv/video.flv"}'/>
          </object>]]></description>
```

However the requirement came up for users not connected to the internet to be able to view the content. I know how to properly embed images and other files within a kmz and have them work, however the flashplayer is not working using the following description tag:

```
            <description><![CDATA[ 
            <object id="flowplayer"
                    data="flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" width="320" height="180"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <param name="movie" value="flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" />
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"movies/flv/video.flv"}'/>
          </object>]]></description>
```

The folder structure in the kmz is as follows:

```
archive.kmz
|- doc.kml
|- flowplayer
   |- flowplayer-3.2.15.swf
|- movies
   |- flv
      |- video.flv
```

It seems as if the flash player is not even loaded (the content renders as if it is attempting to load a flash video but am not seeing any flowplayer images or errors). Has anyone tried something like this or have any ideas why this isn't working via relative pathing?

Comment: Google is fuzzy on what it allows to access in KMZ other than KML and imagery but don't think the Google Earth client allows such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing with a local flv movie and I had the same problem.
It seems that this is because of security problems. I tried to play it in a html page but Internet Explorer blocked it because of ActiveX security. 
A solution that works is to use a small web server (like tinyweb) and replace the links to swf and flv in the kml with http:// localhost/swf/...swf and http:// localhost/mymovies/...flv.
The tinyweb server must be launch before opening the kml (or kmz).
A solution is to make a sfx package to obtain an exe file. When opening the exe file, it is possible to run a script that launch tiny.exe and later the kmz file.
It is a little bit complicated but I think it could be a solution.